# grep ip and port from file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

```
cat file.txt


[...]
                <td><script>                            document.write('89.223.92.30')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('9027')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('185.204.3.105')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('1081')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('91.238.137.108')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('8975')</script></td>


[...]
```

I want to grab ip and port; here is what I do:

```
egrep -oP '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3} | [0-9]{2,5}' file.txt
```

but it does not work (the second pattern matches with the first one among other pbs).

it only works individually.

```
egrep -oP '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt
grep -oP "'[0-9]{2,5}'" file.txt
```

-> works but cant get rid of ' at the begining and at the end; if I remove them in this model, it matches with the ips as well, which is what I dont want.

I also tried :

```
sed 's/                    \<td\>\<script\>                            document\.write\(\'//g' file.txt | sed 's/\'\)\<\/script\>\<\/td\>'//g'
```

the idea here is to trim all garbage before and after ip and port.

result needed:

ip0 port0 (I will store the results in a array that will be used for ssh connection later on).

ip1 port1

ip2 port2
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$ cat ipport.txt  | sed 's/.*write('"'"'//g' | sed 's/'"'"').*//g' | while read -r ip && read -r port; do echo "$ip $port"; done
89.223.92.30 9027
185.204.3.105 1081
91.238.137.108 8975
```

Note, however, that this is generally super error-prone. If your order of ip-port lines will swap somewhere in the sequence, it will all break.

Generally for parsing HTML files you could use some other language, more suited for this, like python and [BeautifulSoup library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Simpler version, without single quote escaping:

```
cat ipport.txt  | sed "s/.*write('//g" | sed "s/').*//g" | while read -r ip && read -r port; do echo "$ip $port"; done
```

Comment: @@favoretti: could you explain: ' " ' " '

Comment: @achille: escaping the `'`, since I went the hard way of habit and quoted sed expression with single quote. Added a simpler version...

Comment: @achille if you got an error message, are you on a Mac by any chance? If so - `brew install gnu-sed` and replace `sed` with `gsed` in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try this `awk` script:

```
awk -F "(^[^']*')|('[^']*$)" 'NR%2 {v = $2; next;}{print v OFS $2}' input.txt
```

or

```
awk -F "(^[^']*')|('[^']*$)" 'NR%2 {v = $2; next;}{print $2 OFS $2}' input.txt
```

#### input.txt

```
        <td><script>                            document.write('89.223.92.30')</script></td>
        <td><script>                            document.write('9027')</script></td>
        <td><script>                            document.write('185.204.3.105')</script></td>
        <td><script>                            document.write('1081')</script></td>
        <td><script>                            document.write('91.238.137.108')</script></td>
        <td><script>                            document.write('8975')</script></td>
```

#### output:

```
89.223.92.30 9027
185.204.3.105 1081
91.238.137.108 8975
```

#### explanation:

```
BEGIN { # pre processig command
    FS = "(^[^']*')|('[^']*$)"; # set field separator to string outside  quote '
    # FS internal variable equivalent to awk argument -F
}
NR % 2 == 1 { # for each odd input line
    v = $2; # save 2nd field in variable v
    next; # skip processing to next line (even input line)
}
{ # for each even input line
    print v OFS $2; # print the saved variable v, right append current 2nd field
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- only interested in lines containing `document.write` (ie, we don't know what other lines look like in the file but we're safe to ignore them)
- each ip/port pair are on consecutive 'document.write' lines in the file
- each `ip` value is a valid IPv4 address
- we don't have to worry about any other types of data on lines with `document.write` and values between the first set of single quotes (`'`)

Our sample data file:

```
$ cat ip.dat
<td><script>   document.write('89.223.92.30')</script></td>
<td><script>   document.write('9027')</script></td>
<td><script>   document.write('185.204.3.105')</script></td>
<td><script>   document.write('1081')</script></td>
<td><script>   document.write('91.238.137.108')</script></td>
<td><script>   document.write('8975')</script></td>
```

We can use `awk` to parse out the ip/port pairs like such:

```
$ awk -F"'" '
/document.write/ && $2  ~ /[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+/ { ip=$2 ; next }
/document.write/ && $2 !~ /[.]/                               { print ip,$2  }
' ip.dat
```

Where:

- `-F"'"` - use single quote (`'`) as our field delimiter
- `/document.write/` - we're only interested in lines with the string "document.write"; ignore all other lines
- `$2 ~ /[0-9]+....[0-9]+/` - if the second field is a 4-tuple of numbers, separated by periods ('.'), we save $2 as the current `ip` value
- `next` - once we have an `ip` value we'll skip to the next line in the input file
- `$2 !~ /[.]/` - if the second field does not contain a period then we'll consider this our port number
- `print ip,$2` - print our ip and port values to stdout

Running the above `awk` script against our data file (`ip.dat`) generates:

```
89.223.92.30 9027
185.204.3.105 1081
91.238.137.108 8975
```